# How can I get data daily from external XML? (like Scheduled Task)

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc

I use Asp.Net MVC on my project..

I want to get data from external Url (like; http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml).. When I get the datas, I save datas to my database..

I want it automaticly, for example; every night at 04:30, without clicking button or calling any page, and my database will be updated..

I will set time or Url on my admin panel..
So if I use Microsoft Scheduled Task, I can't control anything on my control panel..

Comment: Create a scheduled task then.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use asp.net-mvc, build a console application instead and put the executable in your S.O. scheduled task.

Comment: I will set time or Url on my admin panel.. So if I use console application, I think I can't set anything..